# Subscribe static methods to EventHandler Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, event-handling

I have an EventHandler that is static which can be subscribed to from anywhere.

```
public static event EventHandler<CustomEvent> OnChunkLoad = delegate(object sender, CustomEvent ev) {  };
```

I can subscribe non-static methods like so and this work perfectly when the handler is raised.

```
EventHandlers.OnChunkLoad += whenChunkIsLoaded;

public void whenChunkIsLoaded(Object obj, CustomEvent ev)
{
    print("Loaded\n");
}
```

But now I want to be able to subscribe static methods at runtime automatically and allow them to be called when the handler is invoked.

Right now the only way to do this is to have some static method called at startup to subscribe all static methods I want to subscribe.

```
public static class StaticMethods
{

    // call this on startup
    public static void registerMethods()
    {
            EventHandlers.OnChunkLoad += whenChunkIsLoaded;
    }

    public static void whenChunkIsLoaded(Object obj, CustomEvent ev)
    {
            print(ev.DateTime + " : " + obj.GetType());
    }
}
```

Even though this would work it is messy and eventually become very long after awhile.
Any help, Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue and could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it?

Comment: I cannot subscribe static methods without having some kind of subscribeAllMethods() method

Comment: Well it seems to me that yes, at some point you need to tell it which callbacks to add ... If there are many of them then either each class has to add itself as listeners or one centralized class adds them all .. makes little difference I guess... question is: Do they need to be static at all?

Comment: Well I think being able to have the choice of non-static and static would be nice, I think I am going to look more into MethodAttributes and see if I can use them.

Comment: In Unity there is e.g. [`RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) maybe that's what your looking for?

Comment: @derHugo that does seem to be a way around it, have a class with static methods that I want to subscribe just add a subscribeAllMethods() method with that attribute. I am not a huge fan but maybe that is what I will have to do.